# Upload file to MongoDB and to a local server with the same POST request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to make my own upload service, and I want to be able to upload a file in a local folder on my server but also on my mongoDB cloud service (Atlas).

So far, I've done both services separately and they work fine (I made a Node app for uploading files to mongo Atlas and another Node app for uploading files to the server). But now, I would like to unifiy these two into a single node app, where after each POST request, the file gets sent to both Atlas as well as the local folder. I'm using multer and gridfs.

The first attempt was to make two "file-input" fields on my index.html file, and each of those with two different POST requests: one to '/upload' which sends the file to Atlas and the second one to '/uploaddisk' which sends the file to disk. However, the second post request doesn't work (it throws me the error every time I want to submit my file). Uploading the file to mongoDB seems to work just fine every time.

Any ideas how can I do this on a single POST ? Thank you in advance!

Here is the code that I wrote for my `server.js` app:

```
//mongo DATA
const dbURI =
    "myc-atlas-credentials";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// mongoose.connect(bdURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

//init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once("open", () => {
    //initialize the stream
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection("uploads");
});

//creating the storage engine for MONGO
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: dbURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const filename = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
            const fileInfo = {
                filename: filename,
                bucketName: "uploads"
            };
            resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

//set storage engine with multer for disk
const diskstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/'));
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
const diskupload = multer({ storage: diskstorage });

//route for POST - upload data to mongo
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log({ file: req.file });
    // res.json({ file: req.file });
    res.redirect('/');
});

//route for POST - upload data to disk
app.post('/uploaddisk', diskupload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    const file = { file: req.file };
    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file');
        error.httpStatusCode = 400;
        return next(error);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
function fileUpload(req, res, next) {
  upload.single('file')(req, res, next);
  diskupload.single('file')(req, res, next);
  next();
}

//route for POST - upload data to mongo
app.post('/upload', fileUpload, (req, res) => {
    console.log({ file: req.file });
    // res.json({ file: req.file });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: works like a charm. Much appreciated! Shame on me for not thinking about this.